# Swift viewWillAppear not being called first time usingTabBarController

Tags: swift, animation, viewwillappear, tabbarcontroller

So i have a tab bar controller and when I select into the second tab it brings me to a table view controller. I have it setup so that when the viewWillAppear it animates the cells in. The problem I am having is that the first time I go into that view, everything is stationary, but if i go to another tab and come back, everything animates perfectly.

How can I get it to animate in the first time I go to the tab as well?

I have not included code because I do not think it will help answer the question.

Edit* I can go to the tab as many times as I want and it will animate each time, but will never animate on the first load of the app.

Comment: the viewWillAppear will cal each time you go to that screen .As the each tab contains a navigation controller and each navigation controller contains viewcontrollers ... so form my point of view it should work fine.

Comment: @sourav That was my thoughts as well, but after testing on an iPhone, and the simulator, it works perfectly fine everytime I go to it, except the first time I go to it.

Comment: set the delegate and datasource of tableView after viewdid load & reload the table after viewdidload .

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I had a very similar issue with viewDidAppear. My problem was that I called the `viewDidAppear` function in the `TabBarController` to do some stuff but forgot to **call super.viewDidAppear(true)** in this Method. Because of that the viewDidAppear of the child wasn't called. After I added it everything works like a charm.

So be sure to add `super.viewDidAppear(true)` or in your case `super.viewWillAppear(true)` in the TabBarController. Maybe it helps

Comment: Thanks Hero @ inf1783. Worked for me in just Seconds.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. Tried the below in "ViewDidAppear" and it is working.

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in
            self.tableView.reloadData()
        })
```

Comment: That partially worked, the error I'm having with this is it shows the data for a fraction of a second unanimated, and then animates in. I fixed this by adding "tableView.hidden = true" in my viewDidLoad and then when calling the above in viewWillAppear i also inserted "tableView.hidden = false". With a little modification it worked like a charm, thanks a ton.